# adding rows in python to table

Tags: python, numpy

I know in R there is a rbind function:

```
list = c(1,2,3)
blah = NULL
blah = rbind(blah,list)
```

How would I replicate this in python? I know you could possible write:

```
a = NULL
b= array([1,2,3])
for i in range(100):
 a = np.vstack((a,b))
```

but I am not sure what to write in the `a=NULL` spot. I am essentially looping and adding rows to a table. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you know the size a priori?

Answer (score 1):

In numpy, things will be more efficient if you first pre-allocate space and then loop to fill that space than if you dynamically create successively larger arrays.  If, for instance, the size is 500, you would:

```
a = np.empty((500, b.shape[0]))
```

Then, loop and enter values as needed:

```
for i in range(500):
    a[i,:] = ...
```

Note that if you really just want to repeat b 500 times, you can just do:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: b = np.array([1,2,3])

In [3]: a = np.empty((500, b.shape[0]))

In [4]: a[:] = b

In [5]: a[0,:] == b
Out[5]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I write a = np.empty((500, 500)) and loop and set a[1,:] =b but get an error saying output operand requires a reduction

Comment: edited to make the 2nd part more clear, though Ophion's answer is better if you're really just trying to copy an array X times.

Comment: nvm i just did a[i,:] = b.reshape(,500)

Comment: what is b.shape?  If it is asking for a reduction, that's likely because b.shape != (a.shape[1],)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question exactly

```
a = []
b= np.array([1,2,3])
for i in xrange(100):
  a.append(b)
a = np.vstack( tuple(a) )
```

The `tuple` function casts an iterable (in this case a list) as a tuple object, and `np.vstack` takes a tuple of numpy arrays as argument.